# Light.Dialog - настройка темы

Tags: java, android, eclipse, themes

У меня на одном из активити установлена тема Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog. Интересует такой вопрос. Как поменять цвет верхней белой полосы (ActionBar) или вообще её убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте установить фон у окна, используя [setBackgroundDrawableResource](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/Window.html#setBackgroundDrawableResource%28int%29)

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.dialog_box);
```

Answer (score 2):

если же хотите убрать `title`, то можно в коде при подготовке прописать:

```
dialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.AppTheme_NoTitleDialog);
```